# Not receiving notification when using Azure hub notifications rest api from Postman

Tags: azure, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, mule, android-push-notification

I want to integrate Azure push notifications REST API in Mule 4. I have registered my device to the azure portal hub and I am receiving the notification when sending the notification directly from azure portal.

But when using the rest api from postman, I am not receiving it although it returns me a 201 CREATED response.

I am not targeting any tags. I tried direct send, gcm native. could not receive any notifications.

[Direct Send API Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8R61.png)
[Direct Send API Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdQGK.png)

Comment: Could you share the way / part of code you use to call REST API please?

Comment: @YLR I am using direct send Azure REST API. Attached postman snip in above post.

Comment: It is not recommended to use screenshots. Instead use the Code link to the right of Postman, convert to a Curl request and edit the question to paste the request as text. Then paste also the Mule request to compare both.